# pdflatex cannot be found

Tags: mactex, texshop

I have read the many posts on this topic already, but I have had zero success with all of the solutions. Just purchased a macbook (OSX 10.8.2) and used the `mactex` package to run the standard install. `TeXShop` opens up, but when I try to typeset a document, I get the error message :

> "/usr/texbin/pdflatex does not exist. Perhaps TeXLive was not
>   installed or was removed during a system upgrade. If so, go to the
>   TeXShop web site and follow the instructions to (re)install TeXLive."

I'm going to re-download and re-install `mactex`, but I don't see how that will help. I'm totally new at all of this stuff, so go easy.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SE!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/1436/welcome-to-tex-sx)

Comment: Could you run `pdflatex -v` from commandline terminal ? May be TeXshop needs to be configured with the path of the `mactex` bin executables ?

Comment: If TeXshop needs to be configured, you can find  the binaries path using the command `which pdflatex`